# Back and volume buttons not working when app is resumed in certain conditions

Tags: android-activity, touch, google-play-services, leaderboard, start-activity

I'm starting a new activity to display a leaderboard in my Android App.

When the leaderboard activity is displayed, and the user presses the **home** key and then resumes the app (so the leaderboard activity comes up again), and then navigates back to the main activity by pressing the back key, the back key and volume keys stop working).

- I've attempted to override onBackPressed in my activity class.  I can confirm that when this problem occurs, **onBackPressed is not called** (When back / volume is working, pressing back does trigger onBackPressed).
- Normally I get a message in LogCat when I press the back key '**Unimplemented WebView method onKeyDown called from android.webkit.WebView,onKeyDown(WebView.java.2178)**' - Again I can confirm that this message doesn't come up when the back key isn't working

Armed with the above information, I can only assume that it's something to do with the View not having focus or something along those lines.  I would point out that touch input on the screen itself **does** work.  It just seems to be the back and volume keys/buttons that have no effect.

It's an openGL ES 2.0 app so in my onPause() I'm calling view.onPause(); and in onResume, I'm calling view.onResume();

I really have no idea what's going on and I've been on this for 3 days straight so if anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be great.

If the user comes out of the leaderboard and back into the main app *before* they press the home key, then everything is OK, it's just if the home key is pressed while the leaderboard activity is displayed as described above.

So when I'm at the point where the back / volume keys aren't working, if I click my scores button and fire up the leaderboard activity again, they work.  On returning to my activity, they stop working again.

**Not sure if this is relevant at all but the following shows how I'm starting my leaderboard activity**:

```
if (scoresButtonPresses){

    displayLeaderBoard(); 

}

void displayLeaderBoard(){

    //Display the leaderboard if already signed in
    if (checkSignedIn()){               

        startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(getApiClient(), leaderboardID), 1);

    }

    //if not already connected, then set flag and connect to play services before displaying leaderbaord
    else{
        signInAction=SHOW_LEADERBOARD;                      
        getGameHelper().beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
    }   


}

@Override
public void onSignInSucceeded() {

    //If the flag is set, then display the leaderboard
    if (signInAction==DISPLAY_LEADERBOARD){
            startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(getApiClient(), leaderboardID), 1);
    }

    //Otherwise, reset the flag and take no action
    else {signInAction=NO_ACTION;}
}
```

This is driving me crazy so any help or even a nudge in the right direction would be very much appreciated!!

**Edit**

After much testing I have learned a couple of things:

If I remove the view.onPause() && view.onResume() the problem seems to go away.  So this appears to be something to do with the way key events are captured by the view.  Pausing and resuming seems to mess something up.

I have also tried removing the view.onPause() and view.onResume() as above, but instead, putting in View.setVisibility(View.GONE); and then making it visible again in public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus). Again, I get the same problem. Interestingly, when I open the leaderboard, as expected the view's staus is 'gone' then hitting the home key and running the app again, it's set back to 'visible' - I don't understand this behaviour but I'll ask another question for that.

Lastly, and this I find really odd.  If I put my app back to as I had it, then after hitting the home key and relaunching the app **via Eclipse** (and I can do this multiple times) the problem doesn't seem to occur.  So in that respect, it appears to be something to do with touching the screen.

**Edit**

It appears as though this isn't limited to my app. I've tested this on a couple of other apps from the Play store and get the same result.

One app clearly uses a single activity model like mine and the back and volume stop working throughout the app.

The other may use a different activity for it menu and game.  When I test on this app, the back/volume breaks but if you start a game (therefore a second activity), the back key starts working again, even when you return to the first activity (recreated this activity?!)

So maybe I can get around this by ensuring the activity is recreated?  I thought i was already but maybe I'm not getting something.  Maybe it's something to do with the stack.........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no solution to your problem but some additional insights since I'm facing the same bug/problem with the leaderboards and the back button (and it's driving me crazy).

I'm using a single activity with fragments from which I login to Google Play, open Leaderboards and Achievements in the exact way you are doing it (startActivityForResult). Always when I come back from any Google Play Service activity my back button is broken. Sometimes it's even enough if I try to login to Google Play for it to break, meaning the login popup sometimes breaks the back button (but not always).

Some more insights which might help to solve the problem:

- I'm not using OpenGL, so it's not related to this - I'm just using a single activity and fragments
- It's also breaking for me when I just use the back button for going back from any Google Play Activity (I don't even need to go via the home key, just normal back is enough).
- When the back button is broken the Activity is not receiving any Key Events (OnKeyDown, OnKeyUp, dispatchKeyEvent) are all not working, although using the activity and touching it fully works. My guess is that some view is catching the events...

**Edit:**

I also tried checking *activity.getCurrentFocus()* and *activity.hasWindowFocus()* as well as the parent and context classes of *activity.getCurrentFocus()* to see if there is any difference between when it's working and when it's not -  and there isn't any difference...

**Edit:**

It seems that a simple call to **View.requestFocus()** is fixing the problem. For my single activity (using fragments implementation) I have now added:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
    fragment.getView().requestFocus();
}
```

and this seems to be fixing the problem. Sill have to do long term checking if it's always fixed. In your OpenGL implementation I guess you will have to get the main view of the activity in some other way since you are not using fragments.

Comment: Thanks @user3592137, yeah it is extremely irritating.  I feel a little better knowing it's not my code because I sat looking at my code for 3 days solid and came up with nothing.  Indeed, no key events work, so it's almost like you say some view is holding onto key events when the main view is showing.  I downloaded 2 games from the Play Store and it happens there too.  Thanks for the info, at least I know it's not just me who came across the problem!

Comment: Just updated my post with some more things I tried... without success. Currently I'm looking into application wide key listeners in Android, but not sure if this is possible at all.

Comment: Take a look at my recent update, for me View.requestFocus() seems to be fixing the problem.

Comment: I thought this had fixed it but I still get the same problem :-( although it doesn't seem to happen as often as it used to.  I'm putting it down to a bug in Android!! It has to be.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's pretty old question, but for clarification: accepted answer is correct, but incomplete. Focus requesting should be done in onResume, onActivityResult, onSignInSucceeded and onSignInFailed. In first two you have! to call super. Some code:

```
private void requestFocusAfterGooglePlay(){
    if(gimmeFocus==null)
        return;
    View currFocus=getCurrentFocus();
    gimmeFocus.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    gimmeFocus.setFocusable(true);
    gimmeFocus.requestFocus();
    gimmeFocus.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    gimmeFocus.setFocusable(false);
    if(currFocus!=null)
        currFocus.requestFocus();
}

@Override
public void onSignInFailed() {
    requestFocusAfterGooglePlay();
}

@Override
public void onSignInSucceeded() {
    requestFocusAfterGooglePlay();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    requestFocusAfterGooglePlay();
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    requestFocusAfterGooglePlay();
}
```

in my case gimmeFocus is a dummy View created as below:

```
<View 
    android:id="@+id/gimme_focus"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```

I have dynamic layout so I can't never be sure that any view exists in my layout, so I've created this dummy View, it might be also added programmatically. You might choose your fixed View for gaining focus, but rembember that changing focus might change view's look (drawable state).